# Get the hash value from URL in PHP 7.x

Tags: php

I need to implement the 301 redirections using PHP only if the blank hash is appended with the URL. Need to implement only in PHP. I have tried various methods like `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`. But unfortunately, not getting the hash. For Example:

**Case 1:**

- URL: `http://example.test/blog/#`
- Should Redirect (301): `http://example.test`

**Case 2:**

- URL: `http://example.test/blog/#abc` **[No Redirect]**

Please help me to find out. Thanks!

Comment: What's your use case? The browser doesn't send the hash fragment of the URL to the server. "the part after the #, also known as the fragment identifier, is never sent to the server with the request." ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL))

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Actually, I am trying to redirect with the hash finding from URL through JS but my client wants to redirect it through 301 redirects instead 302. Can you please help me how to implement it?

Comment: You just want to redirect if there's a hash? Then you're already done, there will never ever be a hash.

Comment: I had given this fix to my client. But they are insisting with 301 redirects. Do you know any other way to accomplish it?

Comment: Well, you could use JavaScript to trigger a client-side redirection to some specific URL (`http://example.test/redirect-permanent-home`) that contains nothing but the redirection. It's pointless, but so is the business request.